# What is proper word for "get into some place secretly"

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

I was trying to write a line like

> The commandos got into the building without anyone knowing.

But I think that there's a single word for "without anyone knowing". Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: "Secretly", or any synonym of that word, would work.

Comment: *Anyone* is one word. Just like *someone* and *everyone*, *anybody* and *somebody*, or really any pronoun for that matter. As to your question, you are asking for a verb in the title, but for an adverb in the body. Which one is it, now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could say they snuck (or sneaked) into the building. You could say they entered stealthily or secretly or surreptitiously or furtively.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps **infiltrated** would suit your needs:

> 1. a. To pass (troops, for example) surreptitiously into enemy-held territory.
>    b. To penetrate with hostile intent: *infiltrate enemy lines; terrorists that had infiltrated the country*.
> 2. To enter or take up positions in gradually or surreptitiously, as for purposes of espionage or takeover: *infiltrated key government agencies with spies.*
> 3. To cause (a liquid, for example) to permeate a substance by passing through its interstices or pores.
> 4. To permeate (a porous substance) with a liquid or gas.
>
> —source [TheFreeDictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/infiltrated)

For example:

> The commandos *infiltrated* the building.

Answer (score 5):

"The commandos [slipped](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/slip) into the building [unnoticed](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unnoticed)."

Slip -  [with adverbial of direction] go or move quietly or quickly, without attracting notice:

Usage: "We slipped out by a back door".

EDIT:  I misread your question at first.  I would use unnoticed, [unseen](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unseen), or [undetected](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/undetected)

Answer (score 1):

In a conversational context, @Mr. Shiny and New's *sneaked/snuck* is probably the most likely verb, but it's a bit informal, and there's always the problem of [which past tense form to use](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sneak).

For a slightly more "literary/formal" alternative, I'd suggest...

> *They [**stole** into the](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22foretold%20my%20history%22&oq=%22foretold%20my%20history%22&gs_l=serp.3...2694720.2700590.0.2701118.19.19.0.0.0.1.154.1515.16j3.19.0....0...1c.1.27.psy-ab..15.4.302.4kZd7gmocb0&pbx=1&biw=1146&bih=893&dpr=1&cad=cbv&sei=GQJGUsClIYrRsgb524HwBw#q=%22stole%20into%20the%22&tbm=bks) building*.
>    [**steal**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/steal?q=steal) (no object, with adverbial of direction): move somewhere quietly or surreptitiously.

Answer (score 0):

Snakes are pretty sneaky so we can use snake terms like **slithered** or **crept**.

Answer (score 0):

With Halloween in mind:

"The commandos **[ghosted](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ghosted)** into the building, unseen by mortal eye."